# kendo ui validator summary only

Tags: kendo-ui, validation, icenium

All,

I am using KendoUI in Icenium for iOS and Android. When I validate my inputs, I want to save UI space,  so I want to display *, and have the full messages in the summary. My summary displays fine as long as I have the text in the validateMessage parameter in the tag. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Thanks,
B

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you want..download the zip file and get it..

http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/mobile/application/displaying-validation-summary-in-mobile-application.aspx